# feynman scalar integral with on-shell condition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section

There are many integration written down in the standard QFT textbooks for scalar integrals in the computation of matrix elements. For example, in Peskin and Schroeder, we see

$$\int \frac{d^d \ell_E}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{\ell_E^2}{\left(\ell_E^2+\Delta\right)^n}=\frac{1}{(4 \pi)^{d / 2}} \frac{d}{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{d}{2}-1\right)}{\Gamma(n)}\left(\frac{1}{\Delta}\right)^{n-\frac{d}{2}-1}$$

in Eq. (7.86).

Are there some equivalent formula for carrying out phase space integral?

For example, what if I modify the above as
$$\int \frac{d^d \ell_E}{(2 \pi)^d} \frac{\ell_E^2}{\left(\ell_E^2+\Delta\right)^n}\delta(\ell^2)$$
with the on-shell condition coming from the last delta function. Are there some closed formula? Perhaps you can use the identity

$$\operatorname{Im} \frac{1}{p^2-m^2+i \varepsilon}=-\pi \delta\left(p^2-m^2\right)?$$

Comment: Did you try to work it out?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): There is no subscript $E$ on $\ell$ inside the delta function?